# Optimising addition of new column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization

I am adding a column 'DEPARTMENT' to a table 'EMPLOYEE', using the following query.

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD DEPARTMENT varchar(15);
```

The following query is then used to update the DEPARTMENT to 'Technology'

```
update EMPLOYEE set DEPARTMENT = 'Technology' where DEPARTMENT is null;
```

This seemed to be working fine in the development environment due to the limited number of records, but it is taking almost 1 hour in Prod like Environment since there are about 20 million records to be updated in Prod, which is not acceptable.

We are thinking of modifying the update query to remove the where condition as below.

```
update EMPLOYEE set DEPARTMENT = 'Technology';
```

Will this help? or is there another way to optimize this query?

Note: using oracle 11g database

Comment: Remove the `WHERE`-clause?! Do you know what that does? Start with adding an index on `DEPARTMENT`.

Comment: removing the where clause would update all the existing records with 'Technology' which is what I want? Would it become worse?

Comment: try using indexes on the tables you are using..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get the idea that you execute the `UPDATE` after altering the table. In that case the statement is fine and adding an index wouldn't do much I believe as it has to update all records anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The combination of your two statements:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD DEPARTMENT varchar(15);

                  +

update EMPLOYEE 
    set DEPARTMENT = 'Technology' 
  where DEPARTMENT is null;
```

equals to

```
 ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD DEPARTMENT varchar(15) default 'Technology' not null;
```

As you are using Oracle 11g you will add a new column and assign a default value to that column almost in a blink of an eye, because when new column is defined as `not null` Oracle maintains default  value for that column in the data dictionary and it's no longer required for each row to be updated. Also, the newly added that way column with a default value wont consume space until you start insert new rows or update values of `department` column.

Simple demonstration:

```
SQL> create table big_table(
  2    col_1 number,
  3    col_2 varchar2(100)
  4  )
  5  ;
Table created

/* x2 for the sake of demonstration we just insert 600000 rows*/
SQL> insert into big_table(col_1, col_2)
  2    select level
  3         , dbms_random.string('l', 11)
  4      from dual
  5     connect by level <= 300000
  6  ;
300000 rows inserted

SQL> commit;
Commit complete

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'BIG_TABLE');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select count(*) from big_table;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    600000
```

Adding new column + update with default value

```
SQL> alter table big_table add department varchar2(10);
Table altered


SQL> set timing on;

SQL> update big_table set department='Technology';

600000 rows updated

Executed in 28.719 seconds
```

Adding new `NOT NULL` column with default value

```
SQL> alter table big_table 
  2    add department2 varchar2(15) default 'Technology' not null;

Table altered


Executed in 0.015 seconds
```

Comment: Would the same apply for 10g too? As the Prod is on 10g.

Comment: 11g on development, 10g on production?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I know thats not ideal :-(

Comment: @Chillax It's new 11g version feature. Unfortunately, this(maintenance of columns default values in the data dictionary) feature does not exist in 10g version of RDBMS. In 10g assigning default value to a column will require to update each row.